# dynamic empty field should not be stored in database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo, foreach

Here I'm stored some array values into database successfully. But, I have a problem here. For example : I have four input textfields. Assume if user filled three textfields and remaining one field is empty. When I execute this code I got 4 rows in my db table. **3 rows with values and one row without a value** (empty field). (I DONT NEED THAT ONE ROW WITHOUT A VALUE)

But, I need if user didn't entered one field that field should not be stored in database. How to do that? I have posted my codes and image below.

```
<?php
include('config.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $cqty = $_POST['qty'];

    foreach( $cqty as $key => $n ) 
    {
        echo $n ."<br/>";
        try
        {
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO testing ( qty ) VALUES ( :n )");
            $conn->errorInfo();
            $stmt->bindParam(':n', $n, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->execute();
        }
        catch (PDOException $e)
        {
            $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
    if($stmt)
        {
            echo "inserted";
        }
        else
        {
             die(mysql_error());
        }
}
?>
```

and

```
<form action="db.php" method="post">
    qty : <input type="text" name="qty[]" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `empty` to check if `$n` is empty. Use `continue` to skip the rest of the instruction in the foreach loop for that iteration.

```
foreach( $cqty as $key => $n ) 

    if (empty($n)) continue;
    echo $n ."<br/>";
         try ...
```